# Prepared statement inside function that then return results

Tags: php, sql

I've created a function that makes a query of a database table and managed to use the results in another page where the function is called.

Is this approach good?

```
function cart_list($db, $user){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("
SELECT 
    o.username,
    o.quantity,
    p.description,
    p.product_name,
FROM 
    orders as o
INNER JOIN 
    products as p
ON
    p.product_id = o.product_id
INNER JOIN 
    users as u
ON
    o.username = u.username
WHERE 
    o.username ='$user'
AND
    o.checkout ='0'");
return $stmt;
}
```

In the file where I called the function, I used:

```
$stmt = cart_list($db, $user);
$stmt->bind_result(
    $username,
    $quantity,
    $description,
    $product_name);
$stmt->execute();

while($stmt->fetch()){
echo $product_name;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To begin, your indentation is a little off at places, such as in the `while` loop in the second code block, or the `return` statement in the first.

---

It looks like you keep `o.checkout` as an integers like the `= '0'` suggests, but use strings, as the `''` suggests. If you do measure solely in integers, you ought to change the database type.

---

> ```
> WHERE 
>     o.username ='$user'
> ```

You should use [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) instead of straight injection, as it's safer for sanitisation.